# Write to file from within a for loop in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, cat

Let's say I have the following csv file:

```
A,1
A,2
B,3
C,4
C,5
```

And for each unique value `i` in the first column of the file I want to write a script that does some processing using this value. I go about doing it this way:

```
CSVFILE=path/to/csv
VALUES=$(cut -d, -f1 $CSVFILE | sort | uniq)

for i in $VALUES;
do
cat >> file_${i}.sh <<-!
#!/bin/bash
#
# script that takes value I
#
echo "Processing" $i
!
done
```

However, this creates empty files for all values of `i` it is looping over, and prints the actual content of files to the console.

Is there a way to redirect the output to the files instead?

Comment: what's your target idea on those values? post what should be the final result

Comment: `$CSVFILE=path/to/csv` is an error. You likely wanted `CSVFILE=path/to/csv`? Also, `-f4` does not exist in your CSV sample, did you mean `-f1`? With those changes, I am getting `file_A.sh`, `file_B.sh` and `file_C.sh` with the quoted content, not empty files.

Comment: I agree with @Amadan :  Voting to close as a typo, but glad your problem is resolved. If still trouble, try `cat - >> file <<-!` (note the `-` added after `cat`). Good luck to all.

Comment: thank you @Amadan, I corrected the typo in the example, but it seems it's not a good reproducible example of my problem because in my original code I am still getting the output in the console and the "bad substitution" error, so I assume it's something in my script that's not playing well with capturing the output of cat...

Comment: If your [example] is not reproducible, there's really nothing we can do though.

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/path/to/file

values=`cat $FILE | awk -F, '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ' '`

for i in $values; do
 echo "value of i is $i" >> file_$i.sh
done
```

Screenshot

[image: scrot]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    

csv=/path/to/file

while IFS= read -r i; do
cat >> "file_$i.sh" <<-eof
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script that takes value $i ...
#
eof
done < <(cut -d, -f1 "$csv" | sort -u)
```